# Are there any HTML elements that default to "display:inline-block"?

Tags: html

Changing a div or span tag to inline-block feels so dirty. There must be a cleaner solution!
i don't found any HTML element that default to "display:inline-block"

thanks in advance

Comment: I do this all the time and it feels perfectly fine.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

From [the sample stylesheet for HTML 4](http://www.w3.org/TR/CSS2/sample.html): `button`, `textarea`, `input`, and `select` default to `inline-block`, but they aren't generic containers so (presumably given you are talking about alternatives to `div` and `span`) don't suit your needs.

There are no generic containers that default to `inline-block`.

Don't worry about how dirty the *default* rendering  feels to you, it is the semantics that matter.

Answer (score 0):

Maybe Canvas and images ,button, textarea also

Comment: `canvas` is `display: inline`, `table` is `display: table`

Answer (score 0):

In the [Rendering](http://www.w3.org/TR/html5/rendering.html) section of HTML5 CR, several elements are described as having an “expected” binding that causes that the element is “expected” to be rendered as an inline-block. Most of those elements, such as `<input type=text>` are unsuitable for your purposes, because they cannot have any content. Other elements have idiosyncratic rendering features that make it difficult to turn them to normal element.

But technically, you could use e.g. `textarea`. Then you would have to deal with its special rules for whitespace (can be overridden with `white-space: normal`), font size (can be overridden with `font-size: 100%`), font family, etc. So you would get more trouble than you would save.